# log4j.xml is ignored

Tags: java, configuration, log4j

how to use log4j.xml to configure application logging without calling DOMConfigrator(). is there any way? i have seen some code without calling this method. but in my case this file is ignored. and it seems that default behavior is working.

Answer (score 4):

Run your application with this command line argument: `-Dlog4j.debug`

You will then be able to see exactly how log4j is selecting which configuration file to use and if you have a conflicting file.

Answer (score 1):

We never call any `DOMConfigurator`. Just make sure you put `log4j.xml` in the classpath. Also make sure there are no other offending `log4j.xml` files on the classpath.